# Grafana - Limit the amount of shown time series

Tags: grafana, promql

In Grafana, my datasource is a prometheus database and I am querying using the following query:

```
topk(10, sum by (pod) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"^$pod$"}[5m])))
```

The problem is, that due to the rate and the function `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`, I am not receiving the top 10 entries. I am receiving the top 10 entries at a given point of time, which results in many time series displayed in the panel (see the picture below).

[GRAFANA QUERY PICTURE(censored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V03oq.png)

[topk=10, GRAFANA QUERY PICTURE(censored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70IaZ.png)

Question: Is there a functionality in Grafana to limit the amount of time series show in the panel without
using a promQL function like `topk(...)` ?

The expected outcome would be a panel limited to 10 time series, which come from the given query at the top of the post. I am using `Grafana 9.4.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a functionality in Grafana to limit the amount of time series show in the panel without using a promQL function like `topk(...)`?

I don't think so.

But you can use `topk` in a slightly more elaborate query.

```
sum by (pod) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"$pod"}[5m]))
  and topk(10, sum by (pod) (increase(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"$pod"}[$__range]@end())))
```

will be showing top 10 pods by total CPU usage over selected for dashboard time range.

Also, if you are using this in Grafana, consider using `$__interval` inside of `rate` to automatically account for scale change on range of time range selected for dashboard.

Comment: First of all thanks! The second part of the query (topk(10, sum by (node) ....) returns one time series. When using the intersection `and` I get one time series for the entire query. I don't have the key `node` but I tried it with `container`: `sum by (pod) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"$pod"}[5m])))
  and topk(10, sum by (container) (increase(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"$pod"}[$__range]@end())))`. The right hand side results in 10 entries, but the entire query just results in one time series.

Comment: From what I understand, you are using the `and` to get the intersection between the two time series. Now I don't understand why my intersection results in one entry, despite getting 10 entries with topk(10, ....)

Comment: @SimepleServiceDev, sure, it meant to be `pod`. `and` allows to return only those values from the left, that have series with according label sets on the right.

Comment: Can you "inspect" query used by your panel, and post it here?

Comment: @SimepleServiceDev, have you succeeded?

Comment: I used the following query to solve my problem. It is based on your idea, `(sum by (pod) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m]))) and topk(10, sum by (pod, container ) (increase(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m]@end())))`